# neo4j Cypher query with graphId match returns nothing

Tags: playframework, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am using the Play! Framework 2.3 app with neo4j plugin for play - found: [here](https://github.com/tuxBurner/play-neo4jplugin)

I have this model class (code snippet):

```
  @NodeEntity
  @TypeAlias("_Request")
  public class Request {

    @GraphId
    @Indexed
    public Long id;

    @Indexed
    public String requestType;

    @Indexed
    public String requestStatus;
  }
```

When I do this cypher query:

```
  MATCH (n:_Request) RETURN n;
```

It return the Request node and the node id (The assigned graphId value = 138)

Now I run this:

```
  MATCH (n:_Request) WHERE n.id = 138 RETURN n;
```

It returns nothing. Why is this? Can I not make a query on the graphId annotation?
 Help please

Comment: If you use something like `repository.findOne(123)` or a cypher query like `match (n:_Request) where id(n) = {id} return n` and use id:123 as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `id` in `n` is being interpreted as a property of `n` and not of the underlying graph id.

In order to match the node you are looking for you will need to modify your query a little to let Neo4j you are attempting to get the node through its underlying graph id rather than a property named `id`.

```
START n=node(138) RETURN n
```

With that small change you should get the result you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Would it be best to do what you suggested or should I rather generated a unique code and set that as a property of the Node?

Comment: I generally use an `id` property or other unique property rather than Neo4j's native ids. In most cases it is probably fine to use the @GraphId annotation along with my example above. However, I believe it is generally considered best practice to avoid Neo4j's native ids where possible although I don't have a reference handy for you.